# What will happen when malloc non-trivial type?

Tags: memory, c++11, malloc, type-traits

> Only objects (including arrays) of trivial type may be created by a call to std::malloc.

I read it from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_trivial, under the *Note* section.
So if I have a non-trivial type **T**, what will happen if I use std::malloc( sizeof(T) )?

Comment: You get storage good for storing one `T`. What it actually should say is that only objects of trivial type need no construction.

Comment: I corrected the linked reference.

Answer (score 3):

`std::malloc`  is just a "renaming" of old C (not C++) function [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html).

So if it succeeds, it `malloc(sizeof(T))`  returns a pointer to an *uninitialized* memory zone of the size needed by `T`

You need to call some constructor of `T`  on that memory zone. You could use the [placement new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) for that purpose, e.g:

```
 void* p = std::malloc(sizeof(T));
 if (!p) throw your_out_of_memory_exception();
 T* ptr = new(p) T(32);  /// placement new, with constructor called with 32
```

Actually many C++ implementations have their standard `::operator new`  doing something similar. (So `new` calls `malloc` !)