# Is casting and accessing an array of correct alignment and size to a not constructed Trivial Type undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

Is the following code well defined?

```
struct S { int x; };
alignas(alignof(S)) char c_arr[sizeof(S)];
S *s_ptr = (S*)c_arr;
s_ptr->x = 5; // UB or not UB?
```

Note: S is purposfully defined as a [Trivial Type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/TrivialType).

Would the situation change if we made the type none trivial by adding a constructor that just sets X to some arbitrary value without calling it through placement new?

This question is different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107387/what-will-happen-when-malloc-non-trivial-type) question because it does not use malloc and does ask also about none trivial types.

Comment: Yes, this is UB. IIRC the `malloc` (without placement new) is no longer UB since C++20.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Technically, also no longer in C++17 since the change was accepted as a defect resolution while C++17 was the official standard.

Comment: @eerorika A defect, huh. I thought they applied retroactively to every standard version.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat which change would that be? I think I missed it.

Comment: Looks like text book violation of strict aliasing rule to me.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't have the exact proposal/DR, but I have this: http://eel.is/c++draft/c.malloc#4

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I can't understand what it means. Which objects are created by malloc? May be you have a link to any explanation at all?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I remember reading that defect resolutions apply to the current standard and optionally any of the previous ones at the discretion of the implementer. Given that all compilers worked with nominally UB malloc + assign as far as I know, I don't see a reason why not support it. I don't know if that is actually specified anywhere.

Comment: @SergeyA Doesn't the strict alias rule only apply when I change the same memory through two different kinds of representations? Note that I never change anything through c_arr. Also I thought char is excluded from the strict aliasing rule?

Comment: @Brotcrunsher chars exclusion is one way - you can access something as char through pointer which is not a `char*`. It doesn't work the other way around. Since there is no S object pointed to by `s_ptr` (it points to char array) the strict aliasing rule defines this code as UB

Comment: @SergeyA Nope, I didn't explore this topic much yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the following code well defined?

No. It violates the so called [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/98702/2079303).

You must launder the pointer:

```
S *s_ptr = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<S*>(c_arr));
s_ptr->x = 5; // not UB
```

---

Prior to acceptance of proposal [P0593R6](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p0593r6.html), laundering would not have been sufficient. Instead, it used to be necessary to explicitly create the object using placement-new. That is still necessary when the reinterepreted type is not an "implicit-lifetime-type".

Comment: Seems P0593R4 wasn't merged. It mentions `std::bless`, which we don't have.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yeah, that was an old version. I've updated the link.

Comment: Hmm. Can `launder` start object lifetime? http://eel.is/c++draft/ptr.launder#lib:launder doesn't say anything about it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat `launder` can't. But the array of chars can. Standard says: `An operation that begins the lifetime of an array of char, unsigned char, or std::byte implicitly creates objects within the region of storage occupied by the array.`

Comment: [`[intro.object]/10`](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic#intro.object-10) *"starts the lifetime of ... objects ... if doing so would result in the program having defined behavior. If no such ... objects would give the program defined behavior, the behavior of the program is undefined."* This is just brilliant.